# How a property, of type string, is passed

Tags: c#-4.0, properties

I have the following code (note the code below doesnt update the property)

```
private void queryResultsFilePath_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Library.SProc.Browse browser = new Browse();
        browser.selectFile(QueryResultFilePath);
}
```

and

```
public class Browse
{

    public void selectFile(string propertyName)
    {
        ...
        propertyName = browserWindow.FileName;  
    }
}
```

Now i realise that i need to change the second method so that it returns a string and manually assign it to the property in the first example.

What im unsure of is that i thought that when i assigned a ref type as an actual parameter of a method, a copy of its value on the stack (ie its memory address in the heap) was copied to the new location on the stack for the methods formal parameter, so they are both pointing to the same memory address on the heap. So when i changed the value of the formal parameter, it would actually change the value stored on the heap and thus the actual parameters value.

Obviously im missing something since im having to return a string and manually assign it to the property. If someone could point out what ive misunderstood id appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Strings are immutable, but still passed by reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the missing piece here is: strings are immutable.

Although you pass it by reference, as soon as anything attempts to mutate the string, a new string is created leaving the old one intact.

I believe it is the only reference type that has enforced immutability.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx):

> Strings are immutable--the contents of a string object cannot be
>   changed after the object is created, although the syntax makes it
>   appear as if you can do this. For example, when you write this code,
>   the compiler actually creates a new string object to hold the new
>   sequence of characters, and that new object is assigned to b. The
>   string "h" is then eligible for garbage collection.

Further reading:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/e755cbcd-4b09-4a61-b31f-e46e48d1b2eb

If you wish the method to "change" the caller's string then you can *simulate* this using the `ref` keyword:

```
public void SelectFile(ref string propertyName)
{
    propertyName = browserWindow.FileName;  
}
```

In this example, the parameter `propertyName` will be assigned to in the method, because of `ref` being used, this also changes the string that the caller is pointing to. Note here that immutability is still enforced. `propertyName` used to point to string A, but after assignment now points to string B - the old string A is now unreferenced and will be garbage collected (but importantly still exists and wasn't changed - immutable). If the `ref` keyword wasn't used, the caller would still point at A and the method would point at B. However, because the `ref` keyword was used the callers variable now points to string B.

This is the same effect as the following example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyClass classRef = new MyClass("A");
    PointToANewClass(ref classRef);
    // classRef now points to a brand new instance containing "B".
}

public static void PointToANewClass(ref MyClass classRef)
{
    classRef = new MyClass("B");
}
```

If you try the above **without** the `ref` keyword, `classRef` would still point to an object containing "A" even though the class was passed by reference.

Don't get confused between string semantics and `ref` semantics. And also don't get confused between passing something by reference and assignment. Stuff is technically ***never*** passed by reference, ***the pointer to the object on the heap is passed by value*** - hence `ref` on a reference type has the behaviour specified above. Also hence not using `ref` will not allow a new assignment to be "shared" between caller and method, the method has received its own *copy* of the pointer to the object on the heap, dereferencing the pointer has the usual effect (looking at the same underlying object), but assigning to the pointer will not affect the callers copy of the pointer.

Comment: D'oh, thanks very much. It says i cant accept this as the answer for another 10mins.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Look at my answer, with the whole explanation and demo code. You can compile it if you don't belive it.

Comment: @JotaBe Your answer states string is a value type... also wrong.

Comment: @JotaBe You are using `ref` which will change what the caller is pointing to. Using `ref` on a reference type has the same effect.

Comment: On a reference type you don't need to use ref. Why in the case of string you do?

Comment: @JotaBe Because it is immutable. If the method tries to change it, it actually changes a new local copy that is assigned into the parameter variable (much like if you `new MyClass()` into a parameter of `MyClass` into a method, the caller doesn't get your newly assigned `MyClass`). Using `ref` is similar to having a pointer to a pointer, assignment into that variable also affects the method caller. Simply, strings are reference types that are immutable.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11571/discussion-between-jotabe-and-adam-houldsworth)

Comment: +1 Very interesting discussion in chat. Changed my answer to try to make things a little more clear.

Answer (score 2):

I'm really grateful to [Adam Houldsworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/358221/adam-houldsworth), because I've finally understood how the .NET framework uses reference parameters and what happens with the string.

In .NET there are two kind of data types:

- value type: primitive types like int, float, bool, and so on
- reference type: all the other objects, including string

In the case of **reference type**, the object is stored in the heap, and a variable only holds a reference pointing to this object. You can access the object's properties through the reference and modify them. When you pass one of this variables as parameter, a copy of the reference pointing to the same object is passed on to the method body. So, when you access and modify properties, you are modifyin gthe same object stored on the heap. I.e, this class is a reference object:

```
    public class ClassOne
    {
        public string Desc { get; set; }
    }
```

When you do this

```
    ClassOne one = new { Desc = "I'm a class one!" };
```

there's an object on the heap pointed to by the reference `one`. If you do this:

```
    one.Desc = "Changed value!";
```

the object on the heap has been modified. If you pass this reference as a parameter:

```
    public void ChangeOne(ClassOne one)
    {
        one.Desc = "Changed value!"
    }
```

The original object on the heap is also changed, because `one` helds a copy of the original reference that points to the same object on the heap.

But if you do this:

```
    public void ChangeOne(ClassOne one)
    {
        one = new ClassOne { Desc ="Changed value!" };
    }
```

The original object is unchanged. That's because `one` was a copy of the reference that it's now pointing to a different object.

If you pass it explicitly by reference:

```
    public void ChangeOne(ref ClassOne one)
    {
        one = new ClassOne { Desc ="Changed value!" };
    }
```

`one` inside this method is not a copy of the outer refernce, but the reference itself, so, the original reference now points to this new object.

strings are inmutable. This means that you cannot change a string. if you try to do so, a new string is created. So, if you do this:

```
  string s = "HELL";
  s = s + "O";
```

The second line creates a new instance of string, with the value "HELLO" and "HELL" is abandoned on the heap (left to be garbage collected).

So it's not possible to change it if you pass it as a parameter like this:

```
    public void AppendO(string one)
    {
        one = one + "O";
    }

    string original =  "HELL";
    AppendO(original);
```

the `original` string is left as is. The code inside the function creates a new object, and assign it to one, which is a copy of original reference. But original keeps pointing to "HELL".

In the case of **value types**, when they are passed as parameters to a function, they **are passed by value**, i.e. the function receives a copy of the original value. So, any modification done to the object inside the function body won't affect the original value outside the function.

The problem is that, **although string is a reference type,** it looks as if it **behaves like a value type** (this applies to comparisons, passing parameters, and so on).

However, as explained above, it's possible to make the compiler pass a reference type by reference using the `ref` keyword. This also also works for strings.

You can check this code, and you'll see that the string is modified (this would also apply to an `int`, `float` or any other value type):

```
    public static class StringTest
    {
        public static void AppednO(ref string toModify)
        {
            toModify = toModify + "O";
        }
    }

    // test:
    string hell = "HELL";
    StringTest.AppendO(ref hell);
    if (hell == "HELLO")
    {
       // here, hell is "HELLO"
    }
```

Note that, for avoiding errors, when you define a parameter as ref, you also have to pass the parameter with this modifier.

Anyway, for this case (and similar cases) I'd recommend you to use the more natural functional syntax:

```
  var hell = StringTest.AppendO(hell);
```

(Of course, in this case, the function will have this signature and corresponding implementation:

```
  public static string AppendO(string value)
  {
      return value + "O";
  }
```

If you're going to make many changes to a string, you should use the StringBuilder class, which works with "mutable strings".

[How a property, of type string, is passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699103/how-a-property-of-type-string-is-passed/10699760#10699130)

Comment: Since when is string a value type? Second line: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: The exact answer is "since the beginning of .NET framework". See the link in my edit.

Comment: String is a reference type that behaves like a value type via its immutability. It is still passed by reference, but if you want to affect the same underlying value you need to either return a string and set back into the variable or use `ref`. Still, all this is because they are immutable.

Comment: JotaBe, thanks very much for the in depth post. Regarding my situation, im just assigning the file path to the parameter so it shouldnt be changed that often. Ill keep that in mind regarding the stringbuilder class though. Thanks again +1 rep

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable and therefore you are passing copies of them to methods.  This means that the copy changes but the original parameter stays the same.